# Application created by App builder in Oracle Apex is not working

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

I have created a very simple application in app builder in oracle apex. But its not working. When i run this application "Page not found error" is showing. I'm using ORDS 21.0 and APEX 20.0.
Installations are perfectly fine. I've kinda double checked my installations and i think there is no error/defact in my installation.
Otherwise, APEX is working fine just not running my application. Please guide and help me in this !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Home and/or Login URL point to page that doesn't exist. Check that at:

- App. Builder
- select that application
- in upper right corner you'll see **Edit application properties** button
- go to **User interface** tab
- have a look at Home/Login URLs; fix them. For example, in `f?p=&APP_ID.:100:&SESSION.`, `100` represents page number

Comment: I've checked links as per your suggestion but they seem good. The exact error I'm getting is "This page isn't working. Local host redirected you too many times"....